# Assembly 8086 language what does this code mean?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

[image]

I have this code and i wanted to ask how to read it to understand what will be the value inside ax after the program reaches line 24
inside the loop what happens when
mov ax, [sp+4d]
happens does it change the value of ax? to sp+4
i know at the end of the program ax is 15 in hexa just want to know why?
thanks so much

Comment: `[sp + 4]` is not a valid 8086 addressing mode.

Comment: Do not post pictures of code!

Comment: thats a picture from my homework the teacher asked whats ax value at line 24 would love an answer

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your teacher likes to trick you?

The `mov ax, [sp + 4d]` and `mov [sp + 4d], ax` instructions are not encodable (*). Their syntax is wrong because the `SP` register can not be used as an addressing component. So if you can't even assemble the program, how would you find out the value of the `AX` register?

*Maybe the teacher expects you to fix the errors and then report about `AX`.*

In [8086](/questions/tagged/8086) code, you can address the arguments that are on the stack via the `BP` register. Next is a rewrite of the *do_something* proc that is fine. I additionally preserve the value of `BP`.

```
  AX     BP     RET    ARG            Stack ARG is the argument pushed at line 17
\----/ \----/ \----/ \----/                 RET is the return address
^      ^             ^
|      |             |
| SP   | BP          | BP+4
```

```
push bp
mov  bp, sp
push ax
mov  ax, [bp+4]
inc  ax
mov  [bp+4], ax
pop  ax
pop  bp
ret
```

> what will be the value inside ax after the program reaches line 24

At line 23, the `AX` register will still hold zero since the *do_something* proc preserved the value of `AX`.
At line 24, the `AX` register will become 21 because in **the amended program**, `call`ing the *do_something* proc 21 times will have incremented its stacked argument 21 times, going from 0 to 21.

---

(*) The `mov ax, [esp + 4]` and `mov [esp + 4], ax` instructions are fine in code for later cpu's like 80386 because the `ESP` register can be used as an addressing component.